# How to search recommended by collective questions

Tags: support, status-planned, search, collectives

How do I search for questions that are both

1. part of the collective
2. and having an answer(s) recommended by the collective

(I guess the #2 might imply the #1 in some cases.)

I don't see #2 in https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching

I thought something like:

```
collective:"Name" [tag] hasrecommendedby:1
```

where `hasrecommendedby:` is similar to `hasaccepted:`

Comment: If you're only searching for a tag, you can go directly to the collective and use the Filter option to check the "Has recommended answer" attribute as well as select some tags. If you're after a keyword-based search, I _think_ you're out of luck, so you might want to turn this into a [feature-request].

Comment: Something like `collective:"Name" is:answer hasnotice:yes locked:no` nearly matches what you want (recommended answers have a notice on them) but then it also gives other results having notices on them and answers from users recognized by the collective.

Comment: Great suggestions from @41686d6564standsw.Palestine (starting from the landing page) and @blackgreen (using the API).
We'll be adding an `isrecommended:` operator to search as well.

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine Thanks I see that now. However it looks more like finding only the newest ones so atm I think it's not that useful. I think before the actual operator is implemented I'll use the magic combination suggested by AbdulAzizBarkat

Answer (score 4):

I'm not aware of a search operator, but I know how to get the data with the public API.

You can call [this endpoint](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers-by-collective):

```
https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/collectives/<collective_slug>/answers
```

This returns a paginated list of `items`.

- If the item entry has `posted_by_collectives` field, this is an answer posted by a Recognized Member. This not necessarily is also recommended by the collective.
- If the item entry has `recommendations` field, it is an answer from a regular user that was explicitly recommended by the Collective.

The slugs are:

- Go: `go`
- Google cloud: `google-cloud`
- Gitlab: `gitlab`
- Intel: `intel`
- Twilio: `twilio`
- WSO2: `wso2`

[This repository which I own](https://github.com/blackgreen100/SO-Go-Collective) contains a small program written in Go to extract recommended answers information from the public API. The program extracts from the Go collective, but you can replace the slug with whatever you like. You can have a look to see what it looks like. The repository contains also a CSV output dated 2 months ago with the information about the recommended answers divided by Recognized Members and regular users as explained in the bullet points above.

This is the full program in Go (without the type definitions, those are in the repo):

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "net/url"
    "os"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

const host = "https://api.stackexchange.com"
const path = "/2.3/collectives/go/answers"
const pagesize = "50"

func main() {
    page := 1
    obj := fetch(page)

    var data []*Data
    data = aggregateData(obj.Items)

    for obj.HasMore {
        page++
        obj = fetch(page)
        data = append(data, aggregateData(obj.Items)...)
    }

    write(data)
}

func fetch(page int) *Response {
    q := url.Values{}
    q.Set("order", "desc")
    q.Set("sort", "activity")
    q.Set("site", "stackoverflow")
    q.Set("pagesize", pagesize)
    q.Set("page", strconv.Itoa(page))

    resp, err := http.DefaultClient.Get(host + path + "?" + q.Encode())
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    obj := &Response{}
    err = json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(obj)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return obj
}

type Data struct {
    UserID      int64
    UserName    string
    Type        string // recognized,recommendation
    Posted      string // YYYY-MM-DD
    Recommended string // YYYY-MM-DD
    QLink       string
}

func (d Data) AsCSV() string {
    return strings.Join([]string{
        strconv.FormatInt(d.UserID, 10),
        d.UserName,
        d.Type,
        d.Posted,
        d.Recommended,
        d.QLink,
    }, ",")
}

func aggregateData(items []Item) (data []*Data) {
    for _, item := range items {
        owner := item.Owner()
        d := &Data{
            UserID:      owner.UserID,
            UserName:    owner.DisplayName,
            Type:        item.Type(),
            Posted:      item.Answer().DateFmt(),
            Recommended: item.RecommendationDateFmt(),
            QLink:       "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/" + strconv.FormatInt(item.Answer().QuestionID, 10),
        }
        data = append(data, d)
    }
    return
}

func write(data []*Data) {
    f, err := os.OpenFile("file.csv", os.O_CREATE|os.O_WRONLY, 0644)
    if err != nil {
        // dump
        fmt.Println("id,name,type,posted,recommended,qlink")
        for _, d := range data {
            fmt.Println(d.AsCSV())
        }
        return
    }
    _, err = fmt.Fprintln(f, "id,name,type,posted,recommended,qlink")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    for _, d := range data {
        _, err = fmt.Fprintln(f, d.AsCSV())
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }
}
```